# Load codeigniter controller and method from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using jquery ajax in conjunction with $.confirm and I need to figure out how I can load a codeigniter controller/method in response to the $.confirm.  Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: sURL + "utility/ajaxFind_In_tblClients",
    type: "POST",
    data: {ClientNum: ClientNum},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {   
    $.confirm("The email address registered to this account is:\n\n"      
        +json.ClientEmail+
        "\n\nSend password recovery information to this email address?"+
        "\n\nIf you need assistance, please call 888-526-9999.",
        //YES
        function(){ 

        //need to load a codeigniter controller here        

            $.msg("Password recovery information has been sent.\nPlease check your inbox",
            {header:'Password Sent', live:10000});
            $('#ajaxShield').hide();
        },                      
        //NO 
        function(){
            $.msg("Password recovery information has NOT been sent.",
            {header:'Password Not Sent', live:10000});
            $('#ajaxShield').hide();
        } 
    ) //end of confirm
  }, //end of success: function(json), could be YES or NO inside
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert('Problem with utility/ajaxFind_In_tblClients  Status code:'+xhr.status+', Error:'+thrownError);} 
});
```

Looks like I need help for what to do at line 14.  I don't know how to load the codeigniter controller after the user responds "Yes" to the $.confirm.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: You can add another ajax call .Ajax is the only way to call the server side code.Another is form submit or link click but you don't wanna do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function:

```
function send_email(email){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: '/email_controller/send_email',
        data: 'email='+email,
        error: function(){},
        success: function(){}
    }
}
```

and call it in your YES function

Comment: I would also put the entire URL in.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax{
    url: "<?php echo base_url()?>controller_name/function_name",
    type: "POST",
    data: "client="+client,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(){
         //do everything you want for success. it depends on your controller.
    }
}
```